# Elastic Search ICU plugin installed but failure IllegalArgumentException Unknown char_filter type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Im using elasticsearch 5.6.16

I did an installation of analysis icu plugin. But my shard allocation is failed and this the reason behind this.

```
      "node_id" : "wcF3Ob3ATKu5jB3_ur2k8w",
      "node_name" : "prod-08-gce",
      "transport_address" : "10.10.80.12:9300",
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "shard has exceeded the maximum number of retries [5] on failed allocation attempts - manually call [/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true] to retry, [unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-06-19T19:06:20.436Z], failed_attempts[5], delayed=false, details[failed to create index, failure IllegalArgumentException[Unknown char_filter type [icu_normalizer] for [icu_normalizer_casesensitive]]], allocation_status[no_attempt]]]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: did you find the solution for this?